# C programming: Write a program that reads three integers from keyboard and outputs their sum

Tags: c

I have to write code that reads three integers from keyboard and outputs their sum. Does this mean that only integers should be entered, or should it be able to add characters as well? Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d; 

    printf("\n Enter the three numbers:"); 
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); 

    d = a + b + c;  

    printf("sum of numbers is %d", d); 
}
```

Comment: The return value from `scanf` will be 3 if the user entered three decimal numbers. If it's less than 3, then one or more of the variables a,b,c will have uninitialized values.

Comment: Why are you asking random strangers what your professor wants you to do?!

Comment: I'm trying to ensure that my interpretation of the problem is correct.

Comment: Who is better equipped to interpret your assignment? A) people on the internet that are not in your class and lack all context beyond one sentence you provide. B) the professor that gave you the assignment. Think carefully, your grade depends on it and by having posted this, you're already on rocky ground.

Comment: I asked this question because this one sentence was all I was given, and my instructor is not at my disposal 24/7 to ask further questions. If you scroll down, you'll see that a user genuinely helped me, and as such, I did fine in the lab today.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);` parses the input stream for 3 decimal integers optionally separated by white space (spaces, tabs, linefeeds...).

If any other characters are present (such as letters, decimal points, commas...) or if not enough input is available, `scanf` will return a result different than `3` and some of the output variables will not by set.  Always test the return value of `scanf`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a, b, c, d; 

    printf("\n Enter the three numbers:"); 
    if (scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) == 3) {
        d = a + b + c;  
        printf("sum of numbers is %d\n", d);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: "separated by white space " --> white-space is optional.  Input could be "123-456+789".

Comment: @chux: excellent remark!  I was wondering how to separate integers without spaces, I did not think of signs.